# Highcharts ; x-axis scaling issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have following lines of code of highchart:

```
xAxis : {
  "categories" : [100, 200, 250, 300, 400]
}
```

The categories are not equi-distant. But highchart API draws the points with equal distance. This gives wrong interpretation to the user. I want points to be drawn with such distances, which will give user correct information.
The distance shown between two points should be proportionate to the actual distance between two points.

Comment: I advice to set min/max value and tickInterval or use tickPositioner instead of use categories.

Comment: I tried this, but its not working

Comment: Do you have any example?

Answer (score 2):

mentioning them in categories itself makes them equidistant.

if you want to have them graded accordingly then you need change the data array

if for now your data is

`categories: [100, 200, 250, 300, 400]
data: [10, 45, 64, 34 ,91]`

change them like this

`data: [[100,10], [200,45], [250,64], [300,34] ,[400,91]]`

this will work only when the x axis has values(integers) not text.

don't mention any categories

Hope this will help you

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: edited my answer with the explanation that may be the one poonam waikul is looking for

Comment: I don't have access to data. Some data comes to me & I just assign it to xAxis. So, I can't modify the actual data. So, please provide some other solution.

Comment: @PoonamWaikul when you get the data you are storing it in a variable. before creating the chart you can modify the data and then assign

Comment: Thank u very much. I removed categories & changed data points as suggested in the reply. It worked for me.