# Highcharts X-Axis Issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have googled and searched stack overflow alot before deciding to ask this question here because while some questions seemed similar, none of the solutions worked for me.

I have categorised data from sometimes a very wide range eg 1881 - 2012 and would like to dynamically calculate and divide this range into only 11 points on the x-axis which is what I have room to display with no zooming enabled. If data is from from 1881 - 2012, I would like it for example want it to show(not exactly calculated) from 1881, 1901, 1921, 1941.....if its from 1958 - 2013, then 1958, 1968, 1978....

```
xAxis: {
           categories: range(start_year,end_year),
           tickmarkPlacement: "on",
           tickInterval: Math.ceil(range(start_year,end_year).length/11), 
       },

.......

function range(start_year,end_year)
  {
    var years = [];

    for(var i = start_year;i<=end_year;i++)
    {
        years.push(i); 
    }
    return years;
  }
```

What this code does is just skip the labels for certain years but still plots the points on the graph leading to overlapping years on the x-axis.

Any leads on this would be highly appreciated.

Here's the fiddle illustrating my dilemma http://jsfiddle.net/YUPzk/4/

Comment: Are you talking about setting up the axis labeling, or do you want to aggregate the data that is being plotted?

Comment: I need a function to select equal interval points in the rage queried to show all data which will mean skipping some years. The most important this is to show the trend over the selected years. As it is, data labels on the X-Axis overlap making them illegible when you choose a range of more than 12 years

Comment: So you are talking about the axis labeling, and not the data itself?  Highcharts will, by default, choose a suitable tick interval in most cases, if you simply let it (ie don't use categories, and don't specify a tickInterval).  if you set up a fiddle, it'll be much easier to help.

Comment: Fiddle added http://jsfiddle.net/YUPzk/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner) and prepare your own calculating function.
The JavaScript below is one example of how this can be done:
`Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Custom tick positions'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'through axis.tickPositions and axis.tickPositioner'
    },
    xAxis: {
        tickPositions: [0, 1, 2, 4, 8]
    },
    yAxis: {
        tickPositioner: function () {
            var positions = [],
                tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin),
                increment = Math.ceil((this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 6);
            if (this.dataMax !== null && this.dataMin !== null) {
                for (tick; tick - increment <= this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
                    positions.push(tick);
                }
            }
            return positions;
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [ [0, 1],[1, 3],[2, 2],[4, 4],[8, 3] ]
    }]
});`

[The above demo code can be found at this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/n9zmuwoa/)

Comment: Would you be kind enough to provide and example?

Comment: In the related link, demo is attached ;)

Comment: I've been there but the demo doesn't really do what i require. What i need is to have for example years spaced by 10 years without leaving point room in between the years. Thanks for trying to help :-)

Comment: In tickpositioenr you have min/max value, so you can check a "range" between them, then if you check that there are years, you need to reduce ticks in correct dates. The same situation if you range will me smaller.

Comment: Let me do more research on this.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling to get this done, here's what you need because i did lot's of googling with no answers to be found for people experiencing same challenge

[Highcharts ; x-axis scaling issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479994/highcharts-x-axis-scaling-issue?rq=1)